# How to complete this proof?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Prove that if $X_n \to a$ and $X_n\geqslant0$ for all $n$ , then $\sqrt{X_n}\to\sqrt{a}$

solution:

Given any $\varepsilon>0$ , $\exists n_1\in\mathbb N$ such that

$$|Xn−a|< \varepsilon ,\ ∀n\geqslant n_1$$

$−\varepsilon<X_n-a<\varepsilon,\ \forall n \geq n_1$

because $X_n\geqslant0$ then

$0<X_n-a<\varepsilon,\ \forall n \geq n_1$

$\left|\sqrt{X_n}−\sqrt {a}\right|$ =$\frac{|Xn−a|}{\sqrt{X_n}+\sqrt {a}}$<$\frac{\varepsilon×\sqrt {a} }{\sqrt {a}} < \varepsilon$

Comment: If $a>0$, you can use that for $n$ large enough, one has $X_n>\frac{a}{4}$, hence $\sqrt{X_n} + \sqrt{a}> \frac{3}{2}\sqrt{a}$.

Comment: "**then** $0<X_n - a$" is wrong and you don't need it.

Comment: I want to know is there a way to make \frac{\varepsilon}{\sqrt{X_n}+\sqrt {a} less than epsilon to prove \sqrt{X_n} conv to sqrt {a}

Comment: Take $|X_n - a|\le \min(\varepsilon\frac{3 \sqrt{a}}{2}, \frac{3 a}{4})$.

Comment: @Gribouillis how can use this equality to prove sqrt{Xn} conv. to sqrt {a}

Answer (score 0):

Let us suppose first that $a  >  0$. Given any ${\varepsilon}  >  0 , \exists  {n}_{1} \in  \mathbb{N}$ such that

$$\left|{X}_{n}-a\right|  <  \min  \left({\varepsilon} \frac{3 \sqrt{a}}{2} , \frac{3 a}{4}\right) , \quad  \forall  n  \geqslant  {n}_{1}$$

As ${X}_{n}-a  > -\frac{3 a}{4}$, one has ${X}_{n}  >  \frac{a}{4}$, hence
$\sqrt{{X}_{n}}+\sqrt{a}  >  \frac{3 \sqrt{a}}{2}$. It follows that

$$\left|\sqrt{{X}_{n}}-\sqrt{a}\right|  \leqslant  \frac{\left|{X}_{n}-a\right|}{\sqrt{{X}_{n}}+\sqrt{a}}  \leqslant  \frac{{\varepsilon} 3 \sqrt{a}/2}{3 \sqrt{a}/2} = {\varepsilon}$$

In the case where $a = 0$, given any ${\varepsilon}  >  0 , \exists  {n}_{1} \in  \mathbb{N}$ such that

$$\left|{X}_{n}-0\right|  <  {{\varepsilon}}^{2} , \quad  \forall  n  \geqslant  {n}_{1}$$

One has

$$\left|\sqrt{{X}_{n}}-0\right|  <  {\varepsilon} , \quad  \forall  n  \geqslant  {n}_{1}$$